# find all prime numbers $p$ for which $p$ divides $n^3+3$ and also divides $n^5+5$,where $n$ is a positive integer

Tags: prime-numbers, divisibility

I know when $n$ is odd, then $p=2$ satisfies the condition, but is there any other possible value for $p$?

Comment: Hint: $p$ must also divide $3n^2-5$. Why? Can you continue from there?

Comment: (Also, as a heads-up: this question needs some context. Where did you come across the problem? What have you tried (other than the obvious $p=2$ case) and what are your thoughts on it?)

Answer (score 1):

Good day! If $p$ divides $n^3+3$ and $n^5+5$, $p$ divides $(n^3)^5+3^5$ and $p$ divides $(n^5)^3+5^3$. Therefore $p$ divides $3^5-5^3=118=2\cdot59$. Then $p=2$ or $59$.

Comment: But $p=59$ not match. If $p=59$ : $p$ divides $9+5n$ and $n=14$ (mod $p$). However $59$ not divide $14^3+3$.